# Dataset not found .. Missing Path .. while training the model using yolo v8

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, yolo, yolov7

code cell-

```
    from ultralytics import YOLO
    model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
    results =  model.train(data="/workspace/awadh/nvidia/apis_mellifera/v8/datasets/Apis_mellifera_IIT_front_view-1/data.yaml", epochs=200, batch=16, imgsz=640)
```

Error displayed-

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/utils.py in check_dataset_yaml(dataset, autodownload)
    232                 LOGGER.warning(msg)
    233             else:
--> 234                 raise FileNotFoundError(msg)
    235             t = time.time()
    236             if s.startswith('http') and s.endswith('.zip'):  # URL

FileNotFoundError: 
Dataset '/workspace/awadh/nvidia/apis_mellifera/v8/datasets/Apis_mellifera_IIT_front_view-1/data.yaml' not found ⚠️, missing paths ['/workspace/awadh/nvidia/Species_detection/Apis_Mellifera/y8/datasets/Apis_mellifera_IIT_front_view-1/valid/images']
```

So, the same line of codes are working in google colab but when I am using jupyter it is not working.The dataset is present in the file location and yet this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you can include your dataset in the 'datasets' directory's root.

Here's the folder structure you should follow in the 'datasets' directory:

```
data.yaml
train
-images
-labels
test
-images
-labels
valid
-images
-labels
```

For your training, check if your dataset is located at 'datasets/data.yaml'

After, you can use this command to train your dataset :

```
yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolov8s.pt data=datasets/data.yaml epochs=100 imgsz=640
```

[Source](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/discussions/6381#discussioncomment-4207298)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - all worked in colab, but could not find paths when run on Docker (explicitly complained about validation path). Setting full paths solved the problem for me. Say, in your example you should change data.yaml as:

train:
/workspace/awadh/nvidia/Species_detection/Apis_Mellifera/y8/datasets/Apis_mellifera_IIT_front_view-1/train/images

val: /workspace/awadh/nvidia/Species_detection/Apis_Mellifera/y8/datasets/Apis_mellifera_IIT_front_view-1/valid/images

test: /workspace/awadh/nvidia/Species_detection/Apis_Mellifera/y8/datasets/Apis_mellifera_IIT_front_view-1/test/images

Answer (score -1):

This has happened to me on a Cloud GPU Instance using ultralytics 8.0.22. Downgrading to ultralytics 8.0.20 solved the issue for me, running the pytorch/pytorch Docker image.

```
pip uninstall ultralytics
pip install ultralytics==8.0.20
```

However, this issue still persists on my local machine running MacOS Ventura (Apple Silicon).